# I need bundle Product options to display automatically - i.e. without having to click the "customize and add to cart" button

Tags: magento2, addtocart, bundled-product, bundle, bundle-product

I am upgrading to Magento 2 and they have changed the way that bundles display. With a brand new clean install of M2.4 I am reluctant to start messing about with the code too much. I thought I had found an extension which does the trick, but in reality, what I need is very simple.
Instead of displaying (and having to click "Customize and Ad to Cart" to see the options, I want the options to display by default.
Please help anyone! This response rate on this forum seems to be abysmal!

Comment: did you get any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

This function at Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View determines if the options should show automatically - isStartCustomization().

The result of that function call is used here - Magento\Bundle\view\frontend\templates\catalog\product\view\summary.phtml

You can hardcode `autostart: true` in here to force auto display.